# DefWndProc(ByRef m As Message), Nothing happens on this code ... Why?

Tags: vb.net

I am currently working on my project that use fingerprint scanner.

```
Const MESSAGE_CAPTURED_OK As Integer = &H400 + 6

Protected Overrides Sub DefWndProc(ByRef m As Message)
    Select Case m.Msg
        Case MESSAGE_CAPTURED_OK
           'do something
        Case Else
            text.Text = m.Msg.ToString + " " + MESSAGE_CAPTURED_OK.ToString
            MyBase.DefWndProc(m)
    End Select
End Sub
```

Here is the code i use to listen when finger place on fingerprint scanner.

When I point my mouse at specific place like button, text etc. I received this value { **13 , 675, 512** }. But when placing finger on fingerprint scanner nothing happens. Why is this happening?

Comment: how is this being called?

Comment: Does it need to call? I thought it always run when form was loaded since it is DefWndProc.